# Модальное окно в JS

Tags: javascript

На сайте с цветами есть различные картинки: розы, орхидеи, ромашки и т.д. Нужно сделать одно модальное окно для всех, но чтобы информация менялась - к примеру, нажимаешь на Розу а там описание Розы, нажимаешь на Ромашку а там описание Ромашки.

Comment: что-то подобное я читала [здесь](https://habr.com/post/153073/). Надеюсь поможет

Comment: Не нашел ответа

Comment: обычный popup/модальное окно с подгрузкой контента через AJAX.

Comment: типа [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/)?